# Image slider with twitter bootstrap responsive layout

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've created my site to have a twitter bootstrap responsive layout but i just added a image slider and cant seem to be able to get it shrink to when you narrow the screen like the rest of my site i have tried to wrap it in  tag but it does not have any effect can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Here's my Image Slider HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id = "Myhero">

            <div id = "pager"></div>
            <div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pause" id = "pause"></div>
            <div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-play" id = "play"></div>
            <div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" id = "next"></div>
            <div class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" id = "prev"></div>

            <div id = "Myslider">

                <div class = "MyMyitems">
                    <img src = "b1.png"></img>

                    <div class = "Myinfo">
                        <h2>Photo/h2>
                            <p>Photo<a href = "#"></a>Link Here</p>

                    </div><!-- end of Myinfo -->
                </div><!-- end of Myitems -->

                <div class = "Myitems">
                    <img src = "b1.png"></img>

                    <div class = "Myinfo">
                        <h2>Photo/h2>
                            <p>Photo<a href = "#"></a>Link Here</p>

                    </div><!-- end of Myinfo -->
                </div><!-- end of Myitems -->

                <div class = "Myitems">
                    <img src = "b1.png"></img>

                    <div class = "Myinfo">
                        <h2>Photo/h2>
                            <p>Photo<a href = "#"></a>Link Here</p>

                    </div><!-- end of Myinfo -->
                </div><!-- end of Myitems -->

                <div class = "Myitems">
                    <img src = "b1.png"></img>

                    <div class = "Myinfo">
                        <h2>Photo/h2>
                            <p>Photo<a href = "#"></a>Link Here</p>

                    </div><!-- end of Myinfo -->
                </div><!-- end of Myitems -->

                <div class = "Myitems">
                    <img src = "b1.png"></img>

                    <div class = "Myinfo">
                        <h2>Photo/h2>
                            <p>Photo<a href = "#"></a>Link Here</p>

                    </div><!-- end of Myinfo -->
                </div><!-- end of Myitems -->

                <div class = "Myitems">
                    <img src = "b1.png"></img>

                    <div class = "Myinfo">
                        <h2>Photo/h2>
                            <p>Photo<a href = "#"></a>Link Here</p>

                    </div><!-- end of Myinfo -->
                </div><!-- end of Myitems -->

            </div><!-- slider id -->

        </div><!-- end of Hero -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example on JsFiddle?

Comment: What slider plugin are you using? Is it custom-coded?

Comment: @IndieRok here's a link to the plugin im using http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Could you edit your post to add your CSS and Javascript? It would help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you added twitter bootstrap slider or another. can you share live site url ? You can easily added default bootstrap slider here is code

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="photo.jpg" alt="photo">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            CONTENT
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="photo.jpg" alt="photo">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
                CONTENT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using an outdated version of bootstrap, which is version 2 if I recall. Is code the same for version 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am a complete beginner I created a image slider from an example online. Unknown to me bootstrap has a image slider class and example on its homepage. Apologies I did not mean to waste anyone time!